# Microservices Why Use RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I haven't found an existing post asking this but apologize if I missed it.

I'm trying to get my head round microservices and have come across articles where RabbitMQ is used. I'm confused why RabbitMQ is needed. Is the intention that the services will use a web api to communicate with the outside world and RabbitMQ to communicate with each other?

Comment: You can view bellow link. It has a wide description:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377756/3073945

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In Microservices architecture you have two ways to communicate between the microservices:

- Synchronous - that is, each service calls directly the other microservice , which results in dependency between the services
- Asynchronous - you have some central hub (or message queue) where you place all requests between the microservices and the corresponding service takes the request, process it and return the result to the caller. This is what RabbitMQ (or any other message queue - MSMQ and Apache Kafka are good alternatives) is used for. In this case all microservices know only about the existance of the hub.

[microservices.io](http://microservices.io/) has some very nice articles about using microservices

Comment: If you are on the .net Platform check out NServiceBus (http://particular.net) for asynchronous messaging (and can run RabbitMQ as a transport)

Comment: You say synchrnous mode results in dependency. If you have a central hub that sits outside if microservice, doesnt that also imply dependency?

Comment: @mko, it is. It's even called "Single point of failure".There is no silver bullet, one must weight the pros and cons of both approaches

Comment: @mko I dont really agree with you here. Adding just a central hub is going towards synchronous system. You could also add a message queue locally to (each) microservice. That would be a true async communication.

Comment: @mko ,In that case, how are you going to implement the communication between service A and service B? A must know that B (or it's queue) exists, which is in fact synchronous communication.

Comment: I dont agree with you. You didnt consider loosing an event due to unavailability of a central hub. That is what async is all about

Comment: @mko but the point is that you don't need to know which service is responsible for the message. When you (service A) are contacting service B or multiple services. Therefore -> tightly coupled. With message queues, you don't need to care which services are responsible for the message being processed. You just publish it and the services will read it from the queue.
The queue is not really a "single point of failure" if you have a fault-tolerant cluster of many queues for instance.

Answer (score 49):

A message queue provide an **asynchronous communications protocol** - You have the option to send a message from one service to another without having to know if another service is able to handle it immediately or not. Messages can wait until the responsible service is ready. A service publishing a message does not need know anything about the inner workings of the services that will process that message. This way of handling messages **decouple** the producer from the consumer.

A message queue will keep the processes in your application separated and independent of each other; this way of handling messages could create a system that is **easy to maintain and easy to scale**.

Simply put, two obvious cases can be used as examples of when message queues really shine:

1. For long-running processes and background jobs
2. As the middleman in between microservices

**For long-running processes and background jobs:**

When requests take a significant amount of time, it is the perfect scenario to incorporate a message queue.

Imagine a web service that handles multiple requests per second and cannot under any circumstances lose one. Plus the requests are handled through time-consuming processes, but the system cannot afford to be bogged down. Some real-life examples could include:

- Images Scaling
- Sending large/many emails (like newsletters)
- Search engine indexing
- File scanning
- Video encoding
- Delivering notifications
- PDF processing
- Calculations

**The middleman in between microservices:**

For communication and integration within and between applications, i.e. as the middleman between microservices, a message queue is also useful. Think of a system that needs to notify another part of the system to start to work on a task or when there are a lot of requests coming in at the same time, as in the following scenarios:

- Order handling (Order placed, update order status, send an order, payment, etc.)
- Food delivery service (Place an order, prepare an order, deliver food)
- Any web service that needs to handle multiple requests

[Here](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-09-25-breaking-down-a-monolithic-system-into-microservices.html) is a story explaining how Parkster (a digital parking service) are breaking down their system into multiple microservices by using RabbitMQ.

[This guide](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html) follow a scenario where a web application allows users to upload information to a web site. The site will handle this information and generate a PDF and email it back to the user. Handling the information, generating the PDF and sending the email will in this example case take several seconds and that is one of the reasons of why a message queue will be used.

[Here](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-01-03-a-microservice-architecture-built-upon-rabbitmq.html) is a story about *how* and *why* CloudAMQP used message queues and RabbitMQ between microservices.

[Here](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2019-01-18-softonic-userstory-rabbitmq-eventbased-communication.html) is a story about the usage of RabbitMQ in an event-based microservices architecture to support 100 million users a month.

And finally a [link](https://ghost.kontena.io/event-driven-microservices-with-rabbitmq-and-ruby/) to Kontena, about why they chose RabbitMQ for their microservice architecture: "Because we needed a stable, manageable and highly-available solution for messaging.".

Please note that I work for the company behind CloudAMQP (hosting provider of RabbitMQ).

Comment: Remember that you have to disclose your affiliation with the content of the answers that you post. Since you've written those posts for the company that you work for (a wild guess based on your account name and the author's name) you also have to state that as expressed in the behavior [description for Stack Exchange sites](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):
`Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right, I should add more information from other sources, and I added information about where I work. I will look into the answer again and also into the link you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit MQ provides asynchronous communication. when we need to publish lots of events at same time it is very difficult to store in DB at same time. When event got published, it will send to MQ. From MQ it will be consumed by multiple consumers, you can also store data in MQ based on configuration for few days. Rabbit MQ is best for event-based approach at microservice level.
Ex: order creation and cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

The same question can be why REST is necessary for microservices? Microservice concept is not something new under moon. A long time distribution of workflow was used for backend engineering and asynchronous request processing, Microservice is the same component in a separated jvm which matches with S(single responsibility) in SOLID. What makes it micro SERVICE - is that it is balanced.  And that is the all! Particularly (!), it can be REST Service on Spring Cloud/REST base, which is registered by Eureka, has proxy gateway and load balancing over Zuul and Ribbon. But it is not the whole world of microservices!By the way, asynchronous distributed processing is one of tasks which microservices are used for.  Long time ago services(components) in separated JVM was integrated over any messaging and the pattern is known as ESB. Microservices are the same subjects the pattern. Due to fashion for Spring Cloud REST seems like it is the only way of  microservices. Nope! Message based asynchronous microservice architecture is supported by Vertx https://dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-microservices-with-vertx, for example. Why not to use RabbitMQ as message channel? In this case load balancing can be provided by building RabbitMQ cluster. For example:https://codeburst.io/using-rabbitmq-for-microservices-communication-on-docker-a43840401819. So, world is much wide more.